# Lottery machine comparing arraylists Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to make a lottery machine. As of now I have made 2 randomly generated arraylists. One is the "Winning line" (7 numbers from 1 to 40) and the other is the "guess". I want to be able to create multiple random "guess" lines and I have done that with a for loop. Now my problem is that I want to compare these 2 arraylists. And not just if I get all 7 correct but also if I get 4,5,6 numbers correct. I've been stuck here for quite a while and can't really figure what to do.

I tried to just compare if the arraylists are 100% same but it says that they're same every time. I think the problem might be that I actually return the whole arraylist instead of just the randomly shuffled first 7 numbers. Any advice? Also should I use something else like a hashset instead of arraylist.

```
package randomlotto;

import java.util.*;

public class RandomLotto {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  ArrayList<Integer> pelatutRivit = arvoRivit();
  ArrayList<Integer> oikeaRivi = oikeaRivi();
}

 private static ArrayList<Integer> arvoRivit(){  // here we generate the 
                                                 // "guess" lines of numbers

 System.out.println("Arvotut rivit ovat: ");
 ArrayList<Integer> arvRivi = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
 {
 arvRivi.add(i+1);                      // creating an arraylist 1-40
 }

 for(int x=0; x<10; x++){                // looping the "guess" lines for
                                         // x amount of times

 Collections.shuffle(arvRivi);           // shuffling and getting the first 
                                         // 7 values
 System.out.println("---");
 for(int j =0; j < 7; j++)
 {
   System.out.println(arvRivi.get(j) + " ");
}
}
return (arvRivi);
} 

 private static ArrayList<Integer> oikeaRivi(){  // here we generate the 
                                                 // "right" line of numbers

 ArrayList<Integer> oikRivi = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
 {
 oikRivi.add(i+1);
}

 Collections.shuffle(oikRivi);
 System.out.println("OIKEA RIVI ON:");
 for(int j =0; j < 7; j++)
 {
   System.out.println(oikRivi.get(j) + " ");
 }
 return (oikRivi);
}

}
```

Comment: Hi there! Stack Overflow is not a great place to get debugging help. I recommend that you write out your logic in plain English, one step per line, and then see if that matches the code you've written.

Comment: You should think about storing your random numbers in a data structure instead of just printing out the numbers to the screen and re-shuffling the numbers you have. When you have your random numbers saved in a data structure, then you can loop over them and check if the values are contained in the winning numbers array.

Comment: Hey, I was thinking about doing something like that but I am not quite sure how to go on about it... I will look in to it more thanks. @forgetaboutme

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, you should create a randomized `ArrayList`s of integers and then check if you can find these values in your "oikeaRivi" `ArrayList`.

This method can help you check how many numbers are found:

```
private static int howManyNumbers(ArrayList<Integer> guesses, ArrayList<Integer> answers) {

    int nbOfRightGuesses = 0;
    for(int guess : guesses) {
        if(answers.contains(guess)) {
            nbOfRightGuesses++;
        }
    }

    return nbOfRightGuesses;
}
```